# In Jenkins, prompt user for Passphrase when Deploying

Tags: security, jenkins, ssh-keys

When triggering a deployment is is possible to have Jenkins prompt the user for the SSH-key passphrase to use rather than storing in config?

The key benefit is to prevent the storage of the credentials, an auxiliary benefit is to prevent accidental (or unauthorised) deployments to production.

(Jenkins is running under Ubuntu in AWS)

Would "[Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)"  help?

Comment: You can do it manually then, no need of automation. Check Jenkins credentials feature and at the time of execution you can pass credentials as env variable.

Comment: This is via the GUI and automation is desirable - to a point as this involves several servers & keys